# access array from different class c++

Tags: c++

I am working on a dice game called LCR for school.  I finally got the progam to compile and I have the game routine worked out.  I am now stuck on accessing the array in main from my Player class.  Specifically the Player::setChips.  I probably should be using pointers but I am very rough in that area and any input could be great.  The function is calling fine and the outputs work, but the lines that I commented out obviously do not work but gives the idea of what I want to do.  Thanks.

Here is my code from the LCR Game.cpp:

```
    int main()
{

    // Display Game Rules
    Player::directions();

    // Get # of Players
    int currentPlayer = 0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    const int numPlayers = setPlayers(); //set number of players


    static Player* players = new Player[numPlayers]; //set up array 

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) //set names and chips for each player
    {
        cout << endl << "Enter player number " << (i + 1) << "'s name: " << endl;

        players[i].setName();
        players[i].chips = 3;

    }
    // start game

    cout << endl << "OK Let's play!" << endl;

    while (winner == false) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            // check if player has chips. if not ++i and skip turn
            if (players[i].chips == 0) {
                cout << endl << "Sorry " << players[i].name << " you have no chips, you must skip this turn" << endl;
                ++i;
            }
            cout << endl << players[i].name << " You have " << players[i].chips << " chips " << " press enter to roll the dice" << endl;
            std::cin.ignore();         //wait for keypress
            for (int j = 0; j < players[i].chips || j < 3; j++) {  // player rolls dice up to 3 times or max chips

                Player::setChips();  // call setChips. roll dice & move chips 

                cout << players[i].chips;
                // check for winner after each diceroll
                totalChips = 0;                          // reset chip counter
                for (int k = 0; k < numPlayers; k++) {   //add all chips on table
                    totalChips = totalChips + players[i].chips;
                }

                // check for winner                 

                if (totalChips - players[i].chips == 0) {
                    cout << endl << "Congratulations " << players[i].name << " you win " << players[i].chips << " chips!";
                    winner = true;
                    return 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }





    return 0;
}
```

and a copy of the Player::setChips from the Player.cpp

```
void Player::setChips()
{

switch (Dice::rollDice()) // roll the dice
{
case 1:

    cout << endl << "You rolled <L> "; // subtract 1 chip from player and add one to left 

    //--players[i].chips;

    //if (i = numPlayers) {
    //  ++players[1].chips;
    //  }
    break;

case 2:  
    cout << endl << "You rolled <C> "; // subtract 1 chip from player
    //--players[i].chips;
    break; 

case 3:  
    cout << endl << "You rolled <R> "; //subrtact 1 chip from player and give to right
    //--players[i].chips;
    //if (i = 1) {
    //  ++players[numPlayers].chips;

    break; 

case 4: 
    cout << endl << "You rolled <*> ";
    break; //do nothing

case 5: 
    cout << endl << "You rolled <*> ";
    break; // do nothing

case 6: 
    cout << endl << "You rolled <*> ";
    break; //do nothing
}
}
```

Comment: From inside a "Player" object you have no need of the players array. just use ++chips;  so players[3] gives you a player, players[3].set_chips() invokes set_chips() with access to all of player[3] data.

Comment: I tried simply ++chips and it says "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.  If i try ++ players[1].chips I get identifiers players is undefined.  I know I am missing something simple but I am very new to c++.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your `setChips` function static?

> a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Your error is because the function `setChips` is static while `chips` is not.

If you want your function to be `static`, you need to make `chips` to be static as well. Also, at the top of your .cpp, you need to define `unsigned Players::chips;` then you can just use `++chips` inside your `Player` class functions.

If you don't need your function to be `static`, just remove the `static` from your function and you can still use `++chips` inside your `Player` class functions just fine.

Comment: I made chips static and used chips++.  Worked like a charm.  Once again I was overthinking it.  Thank you everyone!